# GoldenGate SPECIALRUN abending with [OGG-02419] Missing checkpoint file name

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-golden-gate

I have GG working fine with processing updates from source to target. However, I am getting a strange error when trying to do an initial load. I have the extract file from the source and I've set the parameter file to pick it up.  I've also added the replicat with `ADD REPLICAT rlcosmos, SPECIALRUN, EXTFILE dirdat\ld000000`. When I try to run using `START myreplicat` I get and error of "OGG-02419 Missing checkpoint file name". My understanding was that checkpoints were not needed for SPECIALRUN, so I'm a bit confused as to the error, since I can see that the checkpoint file is there. Any ideas?

***[EDIT]***, I tried modifying the configuration file (as PRM FILE2 below) and running as a normal replicat, `ADD REPLICAT rlcosmos, EXTFILE dirdat\ld000000`. The process works that way.

**REPLICAT DETAIL**

```
GGSCI (xdaz002092) 52> INFO REPLICAT rlcosmos, DETAIL

REPLICAT   RLCOSMOS  Initialized   2020-07-19 15:12   Status STOPPED
Checkpoint Lag       00:00:00 (updated 00:50:23 ago)
Log Read Checkpoint  File dirdat\ld000000
                     First Record  RBA 0
  Extract Source                          Begin             End

  dirdat\ld000000                         * Initialized *   First Record


Current directory    C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1

Report file          C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\dirrpt\RLCOSMOS.rpt
Parameter file       C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\dirprm\RLCOSMOS.prm
Checkpoint file      C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\dirchk\RLCOSMOS.cpr
Checkpoint table
Process file
Error log            C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\ggserr.log
```

**LOG FILE:**

```
***********************************************************************
                    Oracle GoldenGate for Big Data
                    Version 19.1.0.0.1 (Build 003)

                      Oracle GoldenGate Delivery
  Version 19.1.0.0.2 OGGCORE_OGGADP.19.1.0.0.2_PLATFORMS_190916.0039
       Windows x64 (optimized), Generic on Sep 16 2019 05:33:49

Copyright (C) 1995, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                    Starting at 2020-07-19 14:52:55
***********************************************************************

Operating System Version:
Microsoft Windows 10, on x64
Version 10.0 (Build 19041)

Process id: 30828

Description:
***********************************************************************
**            Running with the following parameters                  **
***********************************************************************
2020-07-19 14:52:55  INFO    OGG-03059  Operating system character set identified as windows-1252.
2020-07-19 14:52:55  INFO    OGG-02695  ANSI SQL parameter syntax is used for parameter parsing.
2020-07-19 14:52:55  INFO    OGG-01360  REPLICAT is running in Special Run mode.

Source Context :
  SourceModule            : [ggapp.checkpt]
  SourceID                : [../gglib/ggapp/checkpt.c]
  SourceMethod            : [chkpt_context_t::openCheckpointFile]
  SourceLine              : [699]
  ThreadBacktrace         : [14] elements
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\gglog.dll(??1CContextItem@@UEAA@XZ)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\gglog.dll(?CreateMessage@CMessageFactory@@QEAAPEAVCMessage@@PEAVCSourceContext@@IZZ)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\gglog.dll(?_MSG_@@YAPEAVCMessage@@PEAVCSourceContext@@HW4MessageDisposition@CMessageFactory@@@Z)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(ERCALLBACK)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(ERCALLBACK)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(ERCALLBACK)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(ERCALLBACK)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(_ggTryDebugHook)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(_ggTryDebugHook)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(_ggTryDebugHook)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(ERCALLBACK)]
                          : [C:\oracle\product\19\OGG_BigData_Windows_x64_19.1.0.0.1\replicat.exe(CommonLexerNewSSD)]
                          : [C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL(BaseThreadInitThunk)]
                          : [C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlUserThreadStart)]
 
2020-07-19 14:52:55  ERROR   OGG-02419  Missing checkpoint file name.

2020-07-19 14:52:55  ERROR   OGG-01668  PROCESS ABENDING.
```

**PRM FILE:**

```
SPECIALRUN
DISCARDFILE dirrpt\rlcosmos.dsc, purge
ASSUMETARGETDEFS
TARGETDB LIBFILE ggjava.dll SET property=dirprm\cosmos.props
MAP MYPDB.HR.*, TARGET MYPDB.HR.*;
TABLEEXCLUDE MYPDB.HR.EMP_DETAILS_VIEW;
END RUNTIME
```

**PRM FILE2:**

```
--SPECIALRUN
REPLICAT rlcosmos
DISCARDFILE dirrpt\rlcosmos.dsc, purge
ASSUMETARGETDEFS
TARGETDB LIBFILE ggjava.dll SET property=dirprm\cosmos.props
MAP MYPDB.HR.*, TARGET MYPDB.HR.*;
TABLEEXCLUDE MYPDB.HR.EMP_DETAILS_VIEW;
--END RUNTIME
```

Comment: Can the person that voted to close this question please provide a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the Replicat from the command line and not from GGSCI.  When you start it with GGSCI, it expects that you are running an non-Initial load Replicat, ergo the checkpoint file is missing.

replicat.sh paramfile path/to/file.prm reportfile optionaloutputfile

or replicat.exe for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Old post - but posting for other encountering this...

The following worked for me also from GGSCI -
When adding the Replicat, be sure to specify the Checkpoint Table details. For example:

GGSCI> ADD REPLICAT rep_1, EXTTRAIL .\dirdat\d2, CHECKPOINTTABLE ggs_admin.ggschkpt

Notes:

- The above works assuming you have configured a checkpoint table (Specifying its name in GLOBALS and running ADD CHECKPOINTTABLE)
- If you are not using a Checkpoint Table for the replicat, but a file, specifying "NODBCHECKPOINT" should work.

Good luck!